# How to control the padding between image and text in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I use NSTextAttachment for embedding a image in NSAttributedString . But I found the image(the PK Icon) is be so closed to the  text, if I want to make some distance between them , how to achieve this.

[image]

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attri = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",item.title]];
if (item.isPK)
{
    NSTextAttachment *imageAtta = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    imageAtta.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 13);
    imageAtta.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PKIcon"];
    NSAttributedString *attach = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:imageAtta];
    [attri insertAttributedString:attach atIndex:0];
}

self.titleLabel.attributedText = attri;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @DorukhanArslan code is very normal for NSTextAttachment,and i post it

Comment: You may create another NSTextAttachment which is for padding, and place it between your image and text.

Comment: @DorukhanArslan Now , i was using a space between text and image , but i think may be there may be  a better way to control more exactly